# Ruby - I need to convert string into a timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to convert a string that represents a date to a timestamp object in Ruby.

For example:

```
   date_string = "18-Feb-2016 09:01:04"

   convert to a timestamp like so

   2016-02-18 14:01:04
```

I need to save this to a mysql database were the column is type timestamp.

I have researched this for most of the day and can not find a solution.  I know you can use Time.parse but that includes timezone and DateTime.parse().to_time includes the timezone.  Since it has to be a timestamp i can not use strftime method.

I need the time to be included because it will be used for calculation purposes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "timestamp"? You say you want a "timestamp *object*", but  `2016-02-18 14:01:04` does not appear to be an instance of the class `Time`. Or is that string (in which case it needs to be enclosed in quotes) which you want to display by extracting information from a `Time` object?

Comment: How did the hour go from `09` to `14`?

Comment: This should do the trick: `DateTime.parse("18-Feb-2016 09:01:04").to_s(:db)` (see answer below)

Answer (score 5):

> **TL;DR**
>
> ```
> datetime = DateTime.parse("18-Feb-2016 09:01:04").to_s(:db)
> ```
>
> returns
>
> ```
> "2016-02-18 09:01:04"
> ```

Here's a quick explanation...

**1. Convert your string to a Date object with `DateTime.parse`**

You can use the `.parse` method from the `Date` or `DateTime` class in order to parse a string. The parse method will return a Date object like this:

```
$ DateTime.parse("18-Feb-2016 09:01:04")
$ => #<DateTime: 2016-02-18T09:01:04+00:00 ((2457437j,32464s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

`.parse` is a method provided by Ruby.

**2. Format the string with `DateTime.parse.to_s`**

Ruby on Rails gives you access to the [`DateTime.to_formatted_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) method to change the formatting of the Date object prior to storing it in your database.

To match the format that you specified:

```
$ datetime = DateTime.parse("18-Feb-2016 09:01:04").to_formatted_s
```

Note: `to_s` is aliased from `to_formatted_s` and `to_formatted_s` is a method provided by Rails, not Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Use to_datetime method in Rails.

```
"12-10-2015".to_datetime
```

=> Mon, 12 Oct 2015 10:36:00 +0000

http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime

Edited to add precise answer.

Comment: Hi. thank you for responding but this seems to be a rails method not for plain ruby.

Comment: Sorry my bad, @amit sharma's answer seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.to_time` or `.to_datetime`, the `.to_time` returns the date and time with timezone but the `.to_datetime` returns full date with week name but it shows +0000 as timezone, you will see the difference in both the formats, see the following example.

```
# used .to_time

"18-Feb-2016 09:01:04".to_time
## Output
2016-02-18 09:01:04 +0530

# used .to_datetime

"18-Feb-2016 09:01:04".to_datetime
## Output
Thu, 18 Feb 2016 09:01:04 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

I've interpreted the question to be that you wish to convert the string `"18-Feb-2016 09:01:04"` to the string `"2016-02-18 14:01:04"` (generalized to arbitrary date-time strings, of course).

Let:

```
str = "18-Feb-2016 09:01:04"
```

What you want is done in two steps. The first is to convert this string to a `DateTime` object, that is, an instance of the class `DateTime`. The second step is to construct the desired string from the `DateTime` object.

One way to create the `DateTime` object is to use the method [DateTime::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse):

```
require 'date'

DateTime.parse(str)
  #=> #<DateTime: 2016-02-18T09:01:04+00:00 ((2457437j,32464s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

That works fine for the string format you gave, but can be problematic with other formats. For example:

```
DateTime.parse "4-5-16 09:01:04"
  #=> #<DateTime: 2004-05-16T09:01:04+00:00 ((2453142j,32464s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

As long as you know the format that will be used, it's generally better to use [DateTime#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) with the appropriate pattern comprised of *format directives*:

```
pattern = "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"
DateTime.strptime("4-5-16 09:01:04", pattern)
  #=> #<DateTime: 2016-05-04T09:01:04+00:00((2457513j,32464s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

See [DateTime#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) for the format directives.

For the problem at hand:

```
dt = DateTime.strptime(str, "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
  #=> #<DateTime: 2016-02-18T09:01:04+00:00 ((2457437j,32464s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

The second step is to construct the desired string with the above-referenced `strftime` method:

```
dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  #=> "2016-02-18 09:01:04"
```